# adding all values of one list to another

Tags: python

The question I had to answer was:

> Implement a function with signature
>
> ```
> def expand_one_or(course_lists):
> ```
>
> This function takes a list of lists of strings course_lists, and
>   modifies it as follows:
>
> - It finds the first list (call it `lis`) in `course_lists` in which `"/"` occurs.
> - It then finds the coordinate of the first `"/"` in `lis` (say `i`).
> - If `lis[i-1]` and `lis[i+1]` exist and are both courses, `lis` is replaced in `course_lists` with two new lists: a list identical to `lis` but with
>     `lis[i]` and `lis[i+1]` removed, and a list identical to `lis` but with
>     `lis[i]` and `lis[i-1]` removed.
> - Otherwise, all that happens is that `lis[i]` is removed from `lis`.

The code I wrote for this question is:

```
def get_course_details(course_description):
    beg_1 = "<A Name="
    end_1 = "></A>"
    for i in course_description:
        course_desc1 = [course_description[i] for i in course_description]
        course_desc2 = [course_description[i] for i in course_description]
        course_desc1[i] = [i].replace('<a name=','<A Name=')
        course_desc2[i] = course_description[i].replace('></a>','></A>')
        x1 = course_desc1.find(beg_1)
        y1 = course_desc2.find(end_1)
        course_code = course_description[x1 + len(beg_1):y1]
        course_code = course_description.replace('"','')
        beg_2 = "Prerequisite:"
        end_2 = "<br>"
        x2 = course_description.find(beg_2)
        y2_temp = course_description[x2:]
        y2 = y2_temp.replace("<BR>", "<br>").find(end_2)
        prerequisites = y2_temp[:y2 + 1]    
        course_details = []
        course_details.extend([course_code, prerequisites])
    return course_details
```

However I keep getting the error

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `course_description` is a list of string:

replace this:

```
for i in course_description:
```

to:

```
for i in range(len(course_description)):
```

check this demo then you will fix it of your own:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for i in a:
...     print a[i]            # i is the element of a not the index
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> for i in a:
...     print i
...  
a
b
c
d
>>> for i in range(len(a)):     # i in an integer from 0 to len(a)
...     print a[i]
... 
a
b 
c
d
>>> for i,x in enumerate(a):     # enumerate access index and object both in tuple
...     print i,x
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
```

Comment: No, the pythonic way would be to not try and index with `i` but just use `i` *directly*. Or use `enumerate()` to get both an index and the object.

Comment: Besides, there are many other problems in the code that'll fall over once this specific exception is solved.

Comment: i am not talking about the pythonic way, i just suggest him why list why the error is raised

Comment: @beginner_coder: You'll get rid of the indexing error if you replace all `for i in course_description`s with what's in this answer. However new problems will become apparent afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think I am getting the error because the function I had implemented before this only provides a list with one giant value like ['123456789'] and im trying to replace the 1 with a 2.